# Hot to navigate to activity from fragment

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, fragment

This is my first post, so I will try to explain myself the best I can.

This is my first project in android with kotlin, and Im creating a simple app with 3 tabs. Im trying to make a simple navigation from a button in one of the 3 fragments associated with the 3 tab views to a new activity. This button have the function "push" associated.

I attach the code from the fragment, where you can see the function to navigate "push" which start the new activity. If I place that function in the onCreateView section, it works fine when I enter the fragment. I had no problem doing this navigation from an activity to another using a similar button and function but i dont know how fragments properly  works, so i guess there is a thing relative to them i am missing. It seems like the function is not recognized outside the onCreate section, so maybe i have to declare it in another way:

---

class NotificationsFragment : Fragment() {

```
private var _binding: FragmentNotificationsBinding? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?

): View {
    _binding = FragmentNotificationsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

private val binding get() = _binding!!

fun push(view: View) {
    val intent = Intent(activity, tutorialPrueba::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

}

---

I was not able to find any solution that helps me in this case. As long this is my first post, i will thank any help or recommendation relative to the way I posted or how i can make it better. Also sorry for my poor english.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DataBinding, the onClick declared in the layout xml does not work. So to make the button, once pressed, call your method you have to do this:

```
private var _binding: FragmentNotificationsBinding? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?

): View {
    _binding = FragmentNotificationsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    _binding.idOfButtonToPress.setOnClickListener{ //replace idOfButtonToPress with the real android:id of button
       push()
    }
    return binding.root
}

private val binding get() = _binding!!

fun push() {
    val intent = Intent(activity, tutorialPrueba::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```